# Looping through Pandas column to derive values to be added to a different column

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation

I have code to be able to look up addresses and find their area names and cities using Geopy (Google V3). Currently it only works on static addresses, I want to be able to loop through the entire pandas column that contains addresses and output cities and area names each to a different column for each row.

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

address = '1238 Davie St, Vancouver, BC'

geocoder = GoogleV3(api_key='xyzabc')

location = geocoder.geocode(address, language='en')

address_components = location.raw['address_components']

counties = [addr['long_name'] for addr in address_components if 'neighborhood' in addr['types']]
localities = [addr['long_name'] for addr in address_components if 'locality' in addr['types']]
```

Works well, but when I assign df['address_original'] to the address variable, I only get the result for the first row.

Would I need to build a loop for this, or are there other ways?

The output I am getting at the moment is

```
[] [u'Clearwater']
```

which is the result for the first address in the df['address_original'] column. I would like to get the results for all the addresses in the column

Comment: Can you please show an example of the output you get and the desired one?

Comment: @alec_djinn just edited the post, let me know if that's what you meant